# Should I use background workers or timers in this situation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

I am writing a program that manages a bunch of timers.

The user has to start them manually, and is able to get information from each timer, to know the remaining time for example.

I don't want the GUI to freeze, therefore I don't want to have a timer on the main form thread that freezes the whole thing.

So, does the Timer class send the timer on a new thread, or it keeps it on the main UI thread?

Otherwise, should I use a Background Worker to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) event runs on the UI thread.

Instead you can use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) which runs on a worker thread.

Ref. : [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type timer you use, I suggest to read [these](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/03/all-about-net-timers-comparison.html) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) to decide the best for you.